# сrash при подключении библиотеки DFP GoogleMobileAds

Tags: ios, swift

Второй день не могу разобраться в чем дело, стоит задача подключить библиотеку для работы с рекламой, нужна именно эта либа.

> https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/quick-start?hl=ru

Создаю Тестовый проект, все нормально садиться и работает, подключаю к текущему проекту, ни в какую не работает. Предположил что это из за моих либ, и на тестовый проект установил все либы которые лежать в моем проекте, тестовый проект так же прекрасно работает.  Так же есть странность, если устанавливаю через `cocoapods` то крашится сразу, если ставлю методом переноса либы в проект и добавляю таргет, то падает только тогда когда прописываю к примеру это `@IBOutlet weal var banner : DFPBanner!`. Расставил брекпоинты и не попадаю в метод `viewDidAppear` в `ViewController`, а до этого `viewDidLoad`, и `viewWillAppear` заходит.

Вот скрин с error [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`cocoapods` последний, 
`pods`  либы самый последний `7.20.0`, 
версия `Xcode 8.2.1`,

```
deployment ios 9.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все перепробовал ничего не помогало и решил создать чистый проект и потихонечку мигрировать и постоянно билдить проект дабы понять в чем дело, так вот переношу данные с инфоплиста на новый проект и снова тот же краш появился.

Оказалось проблема в этом пункте `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` `string = "whatsapp".`

Если вдруг кто столкнется с этой проблемой то "лезьте" в инфоплист и проверяйте пункт который я указал выше. Всем добра.